# Want to Migrate to Magento from Opencart!

Tags: magento2, migration

We have hired some developers to create a online store for our products, and they have suggested us to go with Opencart. But I researched on Google that Magento is better than Opencart but they are asking us to pay almost double for Magento Development. **Is it possible to migrate to Magento from Opencart after sometime once** We start getting gud no of orders after a year or two. Is it okay to Migrate to Magento. Also, please confirm if using Opencart is a gud Idea instead of Magento.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Magento is a very good ecommerce application and comes 3 different options - https://magento.com/products/magento-commerce

1. Community Edition / Opensource Edition
2. Enterprise Edition / Commerce Edition
3. Cloud Edition

I am a Magento developer since 2008, I can share my experience, hope if that may help you in your decision making:

1. If you are ok with the functionality and theme with minor changes in the images and logos than communicty edition of Magento can suite you as a starting point and later you can upgrade features and theme based on your progress and success, community edition of Magento is Free and only you would need will be developer who can help in day to day activities and Hosting company to host the application + other services
2. You can always contact different Magento Partners / Integration Partners to get the feel before getting too much deeper - https://magento.com/partners/choose
3. Go through the Demo of both the eCommerce application and list down the features you need to start vs things you want, that will help you to understand your need
4. Magento has very big open source community, there is always some sort of help available
5. Marketplace of Magento is huge and there are many plugins / extension / modules readily available to implement something that is not available in Magento's Out of the Box application - https://magento.com/products/marketplace

Also, if you develop and start with Opencart than there are extensions available to migrate data from Opencart to Magento - https://marketplace.magento.com/litextension-opencart-to-magento-migration.html

Hope my answer gives you direction in your exploration.

Answer (score 0):

if you have working opencart shop, just keep it running.
since you did not specify your needs and did not really specify what significant differences and which functions are missing in a particular platform.

it’s hard to advise if we don’t know your market, product and marketing plan.

If you did not conduct such an analysis before starting work on a new store, then it is unlikely that you need something specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible for you to migrate data to Magento at any stage of your business on OpenCart. So if your're planning to switch to Magento, kindly give us a sign where we should accompany your project. WKR.